# Tough Integral in a separable ODE

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Denote $y(x) = y$ for simplicity. I am trying to calculate a solution to:

$$\frac{\sqrt{1-k^2(1+y)^2}}{k(1+y)}  = y'$$

Separating I get:
$$\int  \frac{k(1+y)}{\sqrt{1-k^2(1+y)^2}} dy = \int dx$$, but from here I cannot calculate the LHS integral.

Comment: The integral is of the form $$k^{-1} \int \frac{z}{\sqrt{1-z^{2}}} dz$$ so maybe consider the function $$u = c \sqrt{1-z^{2}}$$ for some constant $c$. Or try using the substitution $u = 1-z^{2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int  \frac{k(1+y)}{\sqrt{1-k^2(1+y)^2}} dy = \int dx$$
Substitute $u=k(1+y)$:
$$\int  \frac{u \ du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}  = k\int dx$$
$$\int  \frac{du^2}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}  = 2k\int dx$$
Substitute $v=u^2$:
$$\int  \frac{dv}{\sqrt{1-v}}  = 2k\int dx$$
$$\int  \frac{d(1-v)}{\sqrt{1-v}}  = -2k\int dx$$
Where $v=k^2(1+y)^2$.
This is easy to calculate now.